# No known conversion for argument from type to type&

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a function that overloads `operator=` in class 'ssm'

```
ssm& operator=(ssm& rhs);
```

Later I use an ssm object (itsSSM) as a member of another class(mt3dset). I use the following declaration to initialize that member in the constructor.

```
itsSSM= ssm();
```

But I am getting an error:

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((mt3dSet*)this)->mt3dSet::itsSSM = ssm()’
>
> error: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ssm’ to ‘ssm&’

Is it a problem with compiler (g++ 4.7)? (Please ask for more information if required)

Answer (score 6):

Nope, it's not a problem with the compiler. You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. Note that Visual C++ has an extension to allow this non-standard feature.

Just change your copy assignent to take its argument as const:

`ssm& operator=(const ssm& rhs);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I overlooked that!

Answer (score 2):

You should make that

```
ssm& operator=(const ssm& rhs);
```

Comment: It'd be nice to explain *why* he should make it that way.